# Collision detection kit with FlashPunk

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

I start creating my flash game using Flashpunk, for collisions i didn't want to use hitboxes because i had images (PNG) with transparent parts in them so i decided to use Collision Detection Kit, i have a problem when creating the collision list, it takes a display object as a parameter and doesn't accept flash punk spritemaps, i tried to cast the spritemap to a flash display object but it's not working, is there a way to use the CDK with flashpunk ?

```
override public function begin():void 
    {

        _player = new Player(100, 100);// Entity

        initCollision(_player.sprPlayer);// The Entity Spritemap
    }


private function initCollision(player:Spritemap):void {

        collisionChecker = new CollisionList(player); // Problem here

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create an empty BitmapData with the same width & height of your Spritemap and then "render" it to that BitmapData, like so:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(64, 64, true, 0);
var sprite:Spritemap = _player.sprPlayer;
sprite.render(bmd, new Point(0,0), new Point(0,0));
collisionChecker = new CollisionList(bmd);
```

That should draw the spritemap's current frame to a BitmapData which you could then use for the CollisionList.  The code above is an example that only demonstrates how to do this.  For your actual code, it would be better to avoid constantly initializing new variables during your collision detection.